# Unable to load WSDL in flex/flash application

Tags: web-services, flash, apache-flex, wsdl

I have problem with loading the Web-service in my flash app. The problem is really annoying, because I can't reproduce it and it appears that it shows up only on some of my client's computers, while on the others everything works just fine. The app is build in Flex 3.6A with the minimum version of flash set to 10.0.0. Let me explain what happens.

User enters the website with flash app - there's a call to the `login` web-service `WSDL`. The `WSDL` is being loaded by the app and no 404 or other errors appear - everything is fine. User then puts his `login` and `password`, clicks "`login`" and the error "HTTP request error - Unable to load WSDL. If currenty online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (url_of_the_wsdl)" pops up. It's funny, because it says that the `WSDL` cannot be loaded, but seconds ago when entering the website the `WSDL` was loaded correctly. The other funny thing is - it happens only on **some** of the computers. We were working on this app long time, we were testing it in different browsers on different computers and not even once we encountered this problem.

I checked if the user's deliver correct data, but that isn't the case - they are correct. I also checked the tomcat logs - everything was fine too; no errors there whatsoever. I thought that maybe this is somehow related to `crossdomain` file, but no - the file structure is correct and it allows everything.

I'm running out of ideas, if anyone can help me I will be thankful.

[EDIT]

Well, it looks like some users just can't access the Axis2 webservices being hosted on Tomcat through port 8080. Funny thing, because they state that no firewalls are up and running. Is it possible that ISP is somehow blocking communication through this port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with blocking the default Tomcat port: 8080. After setting up proper reverse proxy on IIS, everything is working perfectly.